# How do I find a cell value based on if statements?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building a badge sending program using Google sheets and everything is going great so far. There is a control page that once marked yes and the script runs, sends an email to the email listed and inserts information from that page, including the recipients name. I want to be able to find the name of the person I'm sending a badge email to, use that name to activate a sheet, and then date stamp a certain cell on that sheet. I'm having trouble finding the name value.

The email and date stamp is working on the control page, but I'm having trouble figuring out the logic to determine the name value to open each person's individual page. The Logger just shows all the names in the range and I only want the names to show that are receiving emails/badges.

```
function sendEmails3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Badge Issuing Central")

  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process

  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 7);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  data.forEach(function(row,i) {

    var name = row[0]; // First column
    var badge = row[1]; // Second column
    var recomendations = row[2]//third column
    var awarded = row [3] // fourth column
    var email = row [4] // fifth column
    var dateEmailed = row [5] // 6th column



    var emailSent = row[6]; // Seventh column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && awarded == 'Yes') { // Prevents sending duplicates

        var body = 'Hi ' + name + '<br><br>' +
          'Congratulations! You have recieved a badge!<br><br>' +
            'Your teammates think you are doing great lately.<br><br>' +
              'You were nominated at least twice by those around you, and you are being awarded:<br><br>' +
                "<em>" + badge + '<br><br>' + 
                  "Make sure you check out your Badge Pathway to see how you're doing!<br><br>" +
                  'Thanks, <br>' +
                    "Jordan, Mark, and Jarrod";





      var subject = 'Congratulations! You have earned a badge!';
       GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", { htmlBody: body } );
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue(d);


      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && awarded == 'Yes') {


      var nameTab = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues(); 
      Logger.log(nameTab);}

  });}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `row[0]` to `data[0]` and logging that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails3() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Badge Issuing Central")  
  var data=sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow()-1, 7).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var name=data[i][0]; // First column
    var badge=data[i][1]; // Second column
    var recomendations=data[i][2]//third column
    var awarded=data[i][3] // fourth column
    var email=data[i][4] // fifth column
    var dateEmailed=data[i][5] // 6th column
    var emailSent = data[i][6]; // Seventh column
    if(emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT" && awarded=='Yes') { 
      var body=Utilities.formatString('Hi %s <br><br>Congratulations! You have recieved a badge!<br><br>Your teammates think you are doing great lately.<br><br>You were nominated at least twice by those around you, and you are being awarded:<br><br><em> %s<br><br>Make sure you check out your Badge Pathway to see how you\'re doing!<br><br>Thanks, <br>Jordan, Mark, and Jarrod', name,badge);
      var subject = 'Congratulations! You have earned a badge!';
      GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", { htmlBody: body } );
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 7).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }    
  }
}
```